# An example of a Banach space whose evaluation map is not surjective?

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples

I have been giving the following corollary while studying functional analysis

Let $X$ be a normed vector space. Then the evaluation map $$ev : X \to X'' ,  x \mapsto (f \mapsto fx) $$ is an isometry.

I know this is a consquence of the Hahn-Banach Theorem

I have been asked to find an example of a Banach space $X$ whose evaluation map is not surjective.

But since the evaluation is a distance persevering function and is automatically injective how would one find an example of a space whose evaluation map is not a surjective?  I can't seem to think of a Banach space where this is true.
Maybe my understanding of the double dual is too limited ?

Comment: It may help to remind you that spaces where the evaluation map is surjective are called "reflexive spaces".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try $l_1$, whose dual is $l_{\infty}$ by simply assigning

$\begin{equation*}
l_1 \longrightarrow l_{\infty}^* \\
y \longmapsto w_y : l_{\infty} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
\qquad \qquad \quad x \longmapsto \sum_n x_ny_n
\end{equation*}$

Now consider the map

$\begin{equation*}
\lambda : c \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
\lambda(x) = \lim_n x_n
\end{equation*}$

Use Hahn-Banach to prove that it admits an extension

$\begin{equation*}
\widetilde{\lambda} : l_{\infty} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}
\end{equation*}$

but does not exist any $y \in l_1$ such that $\widetilde{\lambda} =w_y$; hence we have

$\begin{equation*}
l_1 \hookrightarrow l_{\infty}^*
\end{equation*}$

which is not surjective, that is, $l_1 \neq l_{1}^{**}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: The dual of $\ell^1$ is $\ell^\infty$, but any non-principal ultrafilter on $\bf N$ gives an element of the dual of $\ell^\infty$ which is not in $\ell^1$.

Answer (score 0):

Take for example $X=L^1(\Omega)$. And consider the Dirac functional in $L^\infty$, defined as the functional $\delta_x:C^0(\bar{\Omega})→\mathbb{R}$ with $\delta_x(f)=f(x)$ and continued to $L^\infty$ by Hahn-Banachs theorem. This is not in the image of the canonical map from $X$ to the bidual $X''$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Argha The answer is very terse and could benefit from a little bit more explanation, but it's an answer...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: I think this is better suited for comment not for answer..

Comment: If by "Dirac functional" you refer to a point mass or the distribution it generates, that is neither in $L^1(\Omega)'$ not in $L^\infty(\Omega)'$. If you refer to something else, what to?

Comment: I refer to the functional $\delta_x: C^0(\bar{\Omega})\to R$. Defined as $\delta_x(f) = x_0$ and continued to $ L^\infty $ by Hahn-Banachs theorem.

Comment: Okay, that works (assuming the $x_0$ is a typo and you meant $f(x)$). But you should say that in the answer.

Comment: Will update it when I am back at computer. Typing on mobile phone. And yes f (x) of course.

Comment: @DanielFischer updated answer